# Magento 2 : No products displaying on sub category pages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, magento2.2, products

On sub category listing pages there should be a grid view of all products in that sub catagory, however the page is not displaying any of the products. The parent categories are set to not show products, but the sub categories were working, so I'm not sure if something's been switched in the admin settings or an update to the code has caused an issue.

I've tried clearing cache and reindexing but still just get header,footer, title and description for the sub category page I'm on.

Magento version is 2.1.7

Comment: Check the Display Settings  of that category. What is set for display mode?

Comment: Display mode is products only

Comment: Then its fine. Also checked the logs, is there any error showing or not.

Comment: The only errors are related to a missing css file, however this error seems to be thrown on all frontend pages.

Comment: Check your configuration on store view level. sometime configurations are being overridden on store view levels. Also, if you choose to show products on both levels ( Parent category and child category ) does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

If you facing CSS missing error for all page.
You need to run these commands from CLI.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```